# Simple UpdateCursor onto new field

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to use the updateCursor in ArcGIS Pro 2.4 to populate a new field in my table and can't get it to work. Situation is like this: I have a table with many fields. One of those fields is "Status1". This field contains text values (for example: "No", "Yes", "ABC123" or nulls). What I need to do is to take everything that is a "No" and put it as "Not Completed" while the rest would be just "Completed" in a new field called "Status2"

My code probably is completely wrong. I have no idea how to access a specific field within a featureclass.

```
with arcpy.UpdateCursor(FC, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if Status1[0] = 'No':
            Status2[0] = 'Not Completed'
        else:
            Status2[0] = 'Pending'
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: If you are using ArcGIS 10.1 and above, it is better to use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`. Now It depends on how you ordered your field names inside variable `fields`, and with if statement, you need to use `==` not one `=` and `Status1[0]` and `Status2[0]` should be `row[0]` and `row[1]` assuming `fields = [Status1, Status2]'.

Comment: I'm on Pro. About the "==" it was just a typo

Comment: @user1503110 that’s an important detail that you should [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments make use of a data access cursor. Use the two status fields as your field input and perform an `if` logic check.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC, ["Status1", "Status2"]) as cursor:
    for stat1, stat2 in cursor:
        if stat1 == "No":
            stat2 = "Not Completed"
        else:
            stat2 = "Completed"
        row = (stat1, stat2)
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the code to data access and tried this code but I keep getting an error with cursor.updateRow(row). Also, for some reason I'm geting warnings in line 2 for stat2 ("defined withough usage) and line 7 for both fields "cannot be defined"

Comment: It worked in the end. One of my indentations was wrong. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Sure thing. Please mark the answer as correct (the check mark)